# textbox moves to the top of last page in word document vba macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a vba macro for a word document. I use vba macro to generate textbox and text to the word document. The issue is that the **textbox moves to the top of last page instead of staying on the first page**.

I don't know what i am doing wrong. **All i need is for that textbox to remain on the first page.** I really need to include the textbox.

below is my code and the output image

```
Dim wrdDoc As Object
Dim tmpDoc As Object
Dim WDoc As String
Dim myDoc As String


myDoc = "myTest"
WDoc = ThisDocument.Path & "\mydocument.docx"

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If wdApp Is Nothing Then
    ' no current word application
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.application")
    Set wrdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(WDoc)
    wdApp.Visible = True
Else
    ' word app running
    For Each tmpDoc In wdApp.Documents
        If StrComp(tmpDoc.FullName, WDoc, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ' this is your doc
            Set wrdDoc = tmpDoc
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If wrdDoc Is Nothing Then
        ' not open
        Set wrdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(WDoc)
    End If
End If




ActiveDocument.Content.Select
Selection.Delete

With wdApp
    .Visible = True
    .Activate

    With .Selection
        Dim objShape As Word.Shape


        Set objShape2 = ActiveDocument.Shapes.addTextbox _
        (Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=400, Top:=100, Width:=250, Height:=60)
        With objShape2
            .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionColumn
            .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
            .Left = wdShapeRight
            .Top = wdShapeTop
            .TextFrame.TextRange = "This is nice and shine" & vbCrLf & "222"
            .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        End With
    End With

    With .Selection
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeParagraph

        For i = 1 To 40
            .TypeText i
            .TypeParagraph
        Next i
    End With
End With
```

[image]

Comment: just some housekeeping stuff - the code you posted does not `dim` the `wdApp` variable you set up. However, you don't need that anyway because you're **already in** word to do your vba. You would only reference word like that if you were creating this with excel's vba (which is, in fact, slightly different)

Comment: wdApp is declared globally in another file

Answer (score 1):

Word `Shape` objects must be anchored to a character position in the Word document. They will always appear on the page where the anchor character is and, if the anchor formatting is not to the page, they will move relatively on the page with the anchor character.

A special case ensues when a document is "empty" (a lone paragraph), so it helps to make sure the document has more than one character in it. In the code sample below an additional paragraph is inserted before adding the TextBox - to the first paragraph.

I've made some other adjustments to the code:

1. Added `On Error GoTo 0` so that error messages will appear. Otherwise, debugging becomes impossible.
2. Removed the `With` for the Word application since it's not necessary when using Word objects
3. Declared and use a Word `Range` object for inserting content. As with Excel, it's better to *not* work with `Selection` whenever possible.
4. Used the `wrdDoc` object you declare and instantiate instead of `ActiveDocument`.

This code worked fine in my test, but I cannot, of course, repro your entire environment.

```
Dim wrdDoc As Object
Dim tmpDoc As Object
Dim WDoc As String
Dim myDoc As String

myDoc = "myTest"
WDoc = ThisDocument.Path & "\mydocument.docx"

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If wdApp Is Nothing Then
    ' no current word application
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.application")
    Set wrdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(WDoc)
    wdApp.Visible = True
Else
    ' word app running
    For Each tmpDoc In wdApp.Documents
        If StrComp(tmpDoc.FullName, WDoc, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ' this is your doc
            Set wrdDoc = tmpDoc
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If wrdDoc Is Nothing Then
        ' not open
        Set wrdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(WDoc)
    End If
End If

wdApp.Visible = True
wrdApp.Activate

Dim i As Long
Dim objShape2 As Word.Shape
Dim rng As Word.Range

Set rng = wrdDoc.Content
rng.Delete

With rng
    .InsertAfter vbCr
    .Collapse wdCollapseStart

    Set objShape2 = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox _
                    (Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                     Left:=400, Top:=100, Width:=250, Height:=60, Anchor:=rng)
    With objShape2
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionColumn
        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
        .Left = wdShapeRight
        .Top = wdShapeTop
        .TextFrame.TextRange = "This is nice and shine" & vbCrLf & "222"
        .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
    End With

    rng.Start = ActiveDocument.Content.End

    For i = 1 To 40
        .Text = i & vbCr
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Next i

End With
```

Comment: i am very grateful for the reply. It worked but the problem I'm having is to format the text using your new procedure. Please show me how to do text formating (e.g. bold, size, underline) with this. I'm used to word.Application.selection

Comment: Could you please ask this as a new question, with a bit of detail or an example & sample code to be sure we're on the same wave-length?

Comment: all my code has been in word.Application.Selection please help me convert the above code to use it OR show me how to do text formating. Pleaseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: PLEASE post it as a new question! there's absolutely nothing about the formatting you want to use in the current question! You need to take a moment to provide an example of what you need to do - in a new question. In Stack Overflow it's one topic / question.

Comment: Though this answer is good. If FOR LOOP is not used to display other contents and we have like five lines of  .Text = "  ", only the fifth one is executed. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for you to look at.

```
'12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
'========1=========2=========3=========4=========5=========6=========7=========8=========9=========A=========B=========C

Option Explicit


Sub textboxtest()

Const my_doc_name                       As String = "mydocument.docx"

Dim my_fso                              As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim my_doc                              As Word.Document
Dim my_range                            As Word.Range
Dim counter                             As Long
Dim my_text_box                         As Word.Shape
Dim my_shape_range                      As Word.ShapeRange

' There is no need to test for the Word app existing
' if this macro is in a Word template or Document
' because to run the macro Word MUST be loaded

    Set my_fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    If my_fso.FileExists(ThisDocument.Path & "\" & my_doc_name) Then
        Set my_doc = Documents.Open(ThisDocument.Path & "\" & my_doc_name)

    Else
        Set my_doc = Documents.Add
        my_doc.SaveAs2 ThisDocument.Path & "\" & my_doc_name

    End If

    my_doc.Activate ' Although it should already be visible
    my_doc.content.Delete

    Set my_text_box = my_doc.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        left:=400, _
        top:=100, _
        Width:=250, _
        Height:=60)

    With my_text_box
        .Name = "TextBox1"
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionColumn
        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
        .left = wdShapeRight
        .top = wdShapeTop
        With .TextFrame
            .TextRange = "This is nice and shine" & vbCrLf & "222"
            .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft

        End With

    End With

    Set my_range = my_text_box.Parent.Paragraphs(1).Range

    'FROM
    '
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shape'

    ' Every Shape object is anchored to a range of text. A shape is anchored
    ' to the beginning of the first paragraph that contains the anchoring
    ' range. The shape will always remain on the same page as its anchor.

    my_range.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

    With my_range
        For counter = 1 To 90
            .Text = counter
            .InsertParagraphAfter
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: all my entire code is done with word.application.selection . How do i bold or fontSize with this your method

Comment: Use intellisense in the VBA IDE to check what options are available.  Click on a keyword and press F1 to bring up the MS help page for that keyword.  In the VBA IDE ensure that all check boxes in Tools.Options.Editor.Code Settings have a tick in them.  Make sure you put option explicit at the top of every module.

Comment: Paragraphformat and Font effects etc are properties of the range. e.g. my_range.font.Size=12 or my_range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment=wdAlignParagraphCenter